# Удаление элементов из очереди

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры, очередь, двусвязный-список

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct Spis2 {
    int info;
    Spis2 *next, *prev;
};
void Del_5(Spis2 *&begin, Spis2 *&end) {
    Spis2 *temp = begin;
    int counter = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        counter++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = begin;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->info % 5 == 0 && temp->info % 2 != 0) {
            //If the first
            if (temp->prev == NULL) {
                if (counter == 1) {
                    begin = end = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    temp->next->prev = NULL;
                    begin = temp->next;
                }
                delete temp;
            }
            //if the last
            else if (temp->next == NULL) {
                temp->prev->next = NULL;
                end = temp->prev;
                delete temp;
            }
            //If the middle
            else {
                temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача - удаление элементов, оканчивающихся на 5, из двунаправленного списка. Однако при выполнении возникает ошибка:Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.

> temp было 0x8123.

И указывает на строку

```
if (temp->info % 5 == 0 && temp->info % 2 != 0) {
```

В чем ошибка и как решить?

Comment: `delete temp;` а на следующей итерации `temp->info`

Comment: if (temp->info % 5 == 0 && temp->info % 2 != 0)   можно заменить на  if (temp->info % 10 == 5) ,  а  причину ошибки указал   VTT

Comment: вы после удаления элемента (`delete temp`) каким-то образом должны перейти к следующему элементу. А Вы к нему не переходите и продолжаете работать с уже удалённым элементом.